# How to get budgetId out of an Adwords response XML?

Tags: soap, xpath, google-ads-api, msxml6, adwords-budgetservice

Context: Windows 7, JScript, Adwords v201309

Given the following (doctored) XML, how do I traverse to the budgetId using XPath?

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Header>
        <ResponseHeader xmlns="https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/cm/v201309">
            <requestId>feeddcaa866554433222211000000000</requestId>
            <serviceName>CampaignService</serviceName>
            <methodName>get</methodName>
            <operations>1</operations>
            <responseTime>29</responseTime>
        </ResponseHeader>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <getResponse xmlns="https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/cm/v201309">
            <rval>
                <totalNumEntries>1</totalNumEntries>
                <Page.Type>CampaignPage</Page.Type>
                <entries>
                    <id>134557899</id>
                    <name>Test Search</name>
                    <budget>
                        <budgetId>123346677</budgetId>
                        <name>Test Search</name>
                        <period>DAILY</period>
                        <amount>
                            <ComparableValue.Type>Money</ComparableValue.Type>
                            <microAmount>1000000</microAmount>
                        </amount>
                    </budget>
                </entries>
            </rval>
        </getResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

So far I've got the following script

```
var oXML = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0');
oXML.async = false;
oXML.validateOnParse = false;
oXML.setProperty("SelectionLanguage", "XPath");
var ns = 'xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"';
oXML.setProperty( "SelectionNamespaces", ns );

oXML.load("response.xml");
var x = oXML.selectSingleNode("/soap:Envelope/soap:Body");
//var x = oXML.selectSingleNode("//soap:Envelope/soap:Body/getResponse/rval/entries/budget/budgetId");
WScript.Echo(x.nodeName, x.nodeValue);
```

This works fine as far as traversing to `/soap:Envelope/soap:Body` but if I try to go further, like `/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/getResponse`, (or even `/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/getResponse/rval/entries/budget/budgetId` as suggested below) I get null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should traverse through `<soap:Body>` instead of `<soap:Header>` to get `<budgetId>` :

```
/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/getResponse/.......
```

This is the exact path to `<budgetId>` given sample XML in this question :

```
/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/getResponse/rval/entries/budget/budgetId
```

**UPDATE :**

Your xml has default namespace (`xmlns="...."`) besides `soap` namespace. In XML all elements without prefix considered in default namespace. And in XPath, all element without prefix considered has no namespace. So you'll need to define another prefix pointing to default namespace url (not sure if this is the correct syntax) :

```
var ns = 'xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:d="https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/cm/v201309"';
```

and use it in XPath statement :

```
/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/d:getResponse/d:rval/d:entries/d:budget/d:budgetId
```

Comment: Erk! I originally had Body rather rather than Header. Shall change it back. Mind you, it still doesn't work.

Comment: updated my answer. Disclaimer: I know XPath, but not experienced with MSXML and.. what is this, Javascript?